# Using Activity method in Own class

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, activity-finish

I am trying to use `finish()` method in non-Activity class but I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.mypackage.MyActivity
```

Here is very easy example what I am trying to do:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    // code here

    // call MyClass.exampleMethod 
}

class MyClass {

    public static void exampleMethod(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        ((MyActivity)context).finish(); // in this line exception
    }   
}
```

Comment: is MyClass the subclass of MyActivity?

Comment: how are you calling the MyClass.exampleMethod..can u post the code?

Comment: No, MyClass isn't subclass of MyActivity

Comment: In that case you need to find some other functionality like Broadcast sender or receiver. or you need to pass object of your activity to my class then using that activity object you can finish it.

Comment: I pass context: MyClass.exampleMethod(MyActivity.this);

Comment: Use an intent from that class an register a broadcast on myactivity to call finish. If your activity has been killed by the system this the intent will be ignored.

Comment: why i want him to check with public static void exampleMethod(Activity context) because if you will look error then it is not able to typecast from android.app.Application to com.mypackage.MyActivity. If you will look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html then you find that context contains android.app.Application So actual thing is we are not able to convert context object to Activity object. Because Activity inherits context so we can easily typcast from Activity to Context but I dont think reverse will be true.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this once. I am not sure but it should work.

```
public static void exampleMethod(Activity my_activity) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(my_activity, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            my_activity.startActivity(intent);
            ((MyActivity)my_activity).finish(); // in this line exception
        }
```

or you can try Broadcast receiver. Here is an example I have given already:
[Pass image from activity to custom view edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580780/pass-image-from-activity-to-custom-view-edit)

If you are facing any problem in broadcast receiver then you can ask.

Comment: startActivity is a method of context not activity

Comment: But you can pass it because Activity inherits context

Comment: Then why again casting to MyActivity?

Comment: Ya that is also correct he can directly use if he want to call function from Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 
 ((Activity)context).finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void exampleMethod(Context context, Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        activity.finish(); // in this line exception
    }
}

MyClass.exampleMethod(getApplicationContext(), this);
```